# Range of feedback resistor value in non-inverting op amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, feedback, non-inverting

Is there any limitation for the range of the feedback resistor in a non-inverting circuit? What happens if I choose feedback resistor very high or very low? What is wrong with choosing a 10M ohm resistor as a feedback resistor? What are the considerations for choosing the range of this resistor (regardless of gain)?

Comment: Sounds like school assignment. What do you know about non-idealities of op-amps? Based on those non-idealities, can you determine why for example 1 milliohm range or 1 gigaohm range would not work?

Comment: @Justme You mean it is because of input offset current? or voltage offset?

Comment: Actually he/she does not mean anything, asks you a question if you are aware of some important properties of a real-world op-amp instead. `it is because of input offset current? or voltage offset?` have you tested this assumption on a simulator or a workbench?

Comment: @RohatKılıç I actually have not tested the circuit on a simulator. and yes I know the basics about opamp but I need to know more practical information

Comment: In general - the selected resistors should be (1) very large if compared with the finite opamps output resistance and (2) pretty small if compared with the input resistance  of the opamp used. Both of these conditions are the basis for the simplified calculations for closed-loop gain and other properties of the gain stage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a non-inverting amplifier configuration, the input is fed to the non-inverting input, and the output of a output-divider is fed directly to the inverting input:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYfjTa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For an ideal op amp, the inputs do not draw current, and in a closed loop configuration just like the one above the input voltages are equal. For real-world op amps, the inputs draw current which is called "input bias current". Sometimes it's not low enough to neglect.

For the circuit above, let's first assume that the input bias current flows into the inverting input pin. This means that input bias current will be **stolen** from the divider's current which is supposed to be \$\mathrm{V_o/(R1+R2)}\$ and equal for both R1 and R2. A KCL run shows us that since the input bias current is non-zero, the current flowing through R1 will not be equal to that of R2, and this will lead to the voltage at the inverting pin, and thus the required gain, to shift. Same thing happens if the input bias current flows out of the pin.

To keep these shifts minimum, the resistances of both R1 and R2 **should be low so that the input bias current can be neglected** among the divider current.

Here's an example: Let's assume the required gain is 2, the input bias current for OA1 above is 10 μA (yes, exaggerated a bit) into the pin, and the peak value of the output voltage is 5 V. If we select both R1 and R2 as 50 kΩ, a max current of 55 μA will flow through R1, and the max current flowing through R2 will be  45 μA accordingly. This will make the divider output to be 2.25 V instead of 2.5 V and this means 10% shift.

If we can decrease the resistances to 5 kΩ for both, the max currents will be 505 μA and 495 μA, respectively and the shift will be 1%. If we further decrease the resistances, the shift will decrease further.

### So why don't we decrease both R1 and R2 to 5 Ω?

This is where the **drive capability** of the op amp comes in. For R1 = R2 = 5 Ω, the output current of the op amp will be 500mA. In theory, the op amp has zero output resistance thus output current can be infinite. But in practice, most op amps have a limited output current of a few tens of milliamps only.

As a conclusion:

- The feedback resistances should be low enough to neglect the input bias currents.
- The feedback resistances should be high enough not to force the op amp into output current limitation.

As a rule of thumb, you can select the divider current as 101% of input bias current.

### PS:

Things get worse for inverting amplifier:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgp1HR.png)</sup>

Since the non-inverting pin is tied to ground, the input signal source will be loaded with R1. During the peak crossings of the input signal, the source should supply a maximum current of \$\mathrm{V_{ipk}/R1}\$. So the lower the feedback resistance, the worse for the signal source.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. I completely understood the subject.